# send sms automatically based on date and time

Tags: android, service, smsmanager

1.hello again i need help i am building an application that stores data such as date,time,phone number and message in the database and on basis of time and date sms should be send automatically by retrieving data from database on particular saved date and time,i had done the below code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // Widget GUI
        Button btnCalendar, btnTimePicker,btnset;
        EditText txtDate, txtTime,txtpno,txtmsg;
        //String pno,msg,date,time;
        // Variable for storing current date and time
        private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        SQLiteDatabase mdatabase=null;
        String pno,msg,date,time;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mdatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("timedb", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        String Time_TABLE="create table if not exists SmsTime (pno TEXT PRIMARY KEY,msg TEXT,date TEXT,time TEXT)";

        mdatabase.execSQL(Time_TABLE);
        mdatabase.close();
        btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
        btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimePicker);
        btnset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnset);

        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        txtpno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpno);
        txtmsg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);

        btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnset.setOnClickListener(this);
        final Handler h=new Handler();

    mdatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("timedb", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
        final Cursor c=mdatabase.query("SmsTime", null,null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO record found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{




            c.moveToFirst();
            while(c.isAfterLast()==false){
                pno=c.getString(0);
                msg=c.getString(1);
                date=c.getString(2);
                time=c.getString(3);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data"+pno+"  "+msg+"  "+date+"  "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 

                 Date date1 = null;
                try {
                 date1 = dateFormat1.parse(time);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 int date1hh=date1.getHours();
                 int date1mm=date1.getMinutes();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hh:"+date1hh+"mm:"+date1mm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
                 Date date2 = null;
                try {
                    date2 = dateFormat2.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "date"+date2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 int date2yy=date2.getYear()+1900;
                 int date2mm=date2.getMonth()+1;
                 int date2dd=date2.getDate();


                 Calendar zCalendarL = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                SimpleDateFormat zDateFormatL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

                String DateTime=date2yy+"/"+date2mm+"/"+date2dd+" "+date1hh+":"+date1mm;
                //String DateTime="2014/01/31 13:00";
            Date d1 = null;
                try {
                    d1 = zDateFormatL.parse(DateTime);
                    //d1 = zDateFormatL.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long diff =Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - d1.getTime()) ;
                long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
                final int sec=(int)diffInSec;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "diff::"+String.valueOf(sec), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "diff::"+String.valueOf(diffInSec), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "year:"+date2yy+"month:"+date2mm+"day"+date2dd,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(sec*1000);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        h.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(pno, null, msg, null, null);
                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message is sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }).start();

                            c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == btnCalendar) {

            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox
                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
        if (v == btnTimePicker) {

            // Process to get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                int minute) {
                            // Display Selected time in textbox
                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            tpd.show();
        }
        if(v==btnset){


            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put("pno", txtpno.getText().toString());
            values.put("msg", txtmsg.getText().toString());
            values.put("date", txtDate.getText().toString());
            values.put("time", txtTime.getText().toString());

            mdatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("timedb", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
        long newid=mdatabase.insert("SmsTime", null, values);
        //mdatabase.delete("SmsTime", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record inserted Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtpno.setText("");
            txtmsg.setText("");
            txtDate.setText("");
            txtTime.setText("");

            mdatabase.close();


        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

2.Now the problem is it sends only one sms at a time to send from database another one again the program should be run,and how should i use services in this code please help me.

Comment: use intent to check wether the message is sent then once its sent or failed send the next one.Also consider using service to doing this kind of job is best practice

Comment: Please tell me how should i use services in this code??

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html there are lot of tutorial available for creating service in android. Please refer it